# Python win32com module save command in external application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with Python and STK integration with the `win32com` module. I need to build STK scenarios and save them, the problem is that I cannot find any saving example on [AGI's documentation](http://help.agi.com/stkdevkit/11.4.0/Content/stkObjects/ObjModPythonCodeSamples.htm). Here is a starting point:

```
import win32com.client

uiApplication = win32com.client.Dispatch('STK11.Application')
uiApplication.Visible = True

root = uiApplication.Personality2

root.NewScenario('this_Scenario')
satellite = root.CurrentScenario.Children.New(18, 'this_Satellite') # eSatellite

input("Press enter to exit script.")
```

How to tell `wind32com` to save the created scenario?

Comment: That is not a `win32com` issue. All `win32com` does is to provide a thin Python wrapper around the COM objects provided by the application you dispatch. `win32com` will let you do whatever the STK11 application will let you do. But you need to look at its documentation to find out what it will let you do. http://help.agi.com/stk/index.htm#training/StartPython.htm

Comment: @BoarGules : The documentation has several examples, but none of these envolve saving a scenario. Also, it seems like their goal is to cell certification courses, so there are no comprehensive lists of methods/functions/whatever made available by the interface.

Comment: Try using PythonWin's `Tools | COM Makepy utility`. It will build early-bind Python wrappers around the COM classes that will at least give you the names of all the classes and their methods.

Answer (score 0):

What works right now:

```
root.ExecuteCommand('Save / * "{}"'.format(scenario_path))
```

Effectively, this is a workaround, the `Save` command is being sent to be executed by STK connect. I give a path to the location I want the Scenario to be saved in, and to my understanding the `*` indicates that everything is to be saved, whereas a single object could ahve been placed as an argument.

From [AGI's documentation](http://help.agi.com/stk/Subsystems/connectCmds/Content/cmd_SaveAs.htm) the syntax of this command is:

```
SaveAs <ApplicationPath> <ObjectPath> "<FilePath>"
```